# How to generate dbca.rsp for oracle db?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I know I can record response file by `./runInstaller -record -destinationFile /tmp/10gR2.rsp`

Can I record dbca response file also? like doing 
`dbca -record -destinationFile /tmp/10gDBCA.rsp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with standard tools.